# How to test whether the mean of an observed time-series is statistically different from the mean of the predicted time-series?

Tags: time-series, t-test, mean, prediction, differences

Let's say I have an observed time-series from $y_1,...,y_T$, as well as an predicted time-series $\hat{y}_1,...,\hat{y}_T$.

I want to test whether the mean of observed values $\bar{y}$ is equal to the mean of predicted values $\bar{\hat{y}}$.

My idea is to calculate the differences $D_1=y_1-\hat{y}_1,...,D_T=y_T-\hat{y}_T$ and denote the mean difference $\bar{D}$. Then, I can calculate $var(\bar{D})$ by $(S_y^2+S_\hat{y}^2)/T-2S_yS_\hat{y}/T$, and finally my test-statistic would be $t=\bar{D}/sd(\bar{D})$.

However, I'm not sure whether this is correct. I'm ready to assume that the observed data follow a normal distribution, and my estimation methods also yields asymptotically normal-distributed predictions.

Can anyone clarify how a proper statistical test should be carried out in order to determine whether the means of the two series are equal or not?

Thanks!